# Is there an 'optimal' buffer size when using send()?

Tags: sockets, winsock, send, file-transfer

Let's say you're transferring a file of arbitrary length in chunks over TCP/IP:

```
looping...
    read(buffer, LENGTH)
    send(mysocket, buffer, LENGTH, flags)
```

My question is, what would be optimal value of LENGTH? Or does it not matter at all? I've seen everything from 256 bytes to 8192 bytes being used.

Comment: Note that this loop is already incorrect. The length supplied to the send() call should be the length returned by the read() call. You can't assume it filled the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you mean by optimal.  For optimal usage of the bandwidth, you want to maximize the packet size so send at least the network packet size (which on Ethernet is usually about 1500 bytes).   If you are reading from disk 4096 or 8192 bytes would be a good value.

Comment: The size is usually chosen to be a multiple of the systems page size to optimize memory handling.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)

Answer (score 0):

If your buffer size translates into packet size, then shorter buffers are better -- less to retransmit in event of a packet error.

ATM took this to the extreme with a 54-byte packet.

But depending upon your library, it might be doing some buffering of its own and setting its packet size independantly.  YMMV.

Comment: There's also going to be some fixed-size stuff attached to each packet, so making the packet size smaller reduces the amount of bandwidth being used by actual data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending large amounts of data over a high latency connection, you can get better throughput with a larger send buffer.  Here is a good explanation:
http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/11/17/tcp_tuning.html